# Android RingtoneManager

Tags: android, audio, ringtonemanager

I get Ringtones by this following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "ringtone");
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
startActivity(intent);
```

but i dont know how to synchronize this ringtones with headphones. Eg, i want to play ringtone and this ringtone is playing outside of headphones.

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397934/how-to-play-audio-through-speaker-even-when-headset-is-plugged-in

Comment: what should i change RingtoneManager class, or my Activity